# Проблема с PHP функцией printf

Tags: php, printf

Здравствуйте!

Вот уже несколько дней не могу понять почему не выполняется функция print. Сначала предполагал, что проблема в остальном коде страницы, ан нет ... исключаю скрипт всё работает. Обычно такое  у меня происходило когда в скрипте присутствовали запрещёные символы. Вроде всё просмотрел , но всё по прежнему. Посмотрите пожалуйста код, может что-нибудь заметите. Заранее благодарен!

Код такой:

```
printf ("<table border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <td><table width='950' height='240' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
      <tr>
        <td width='502' valign='top'><h1>%s-комн. квартира в строящемя доме на проспекте Фрунзе</h1>
          <h2>Квартира № %s </h2>
          <table width='445' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <td><table width='445' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>
      <tr>
        <td width='179' bgcolor='#F0F5FF'><strong>Количество комнат: </strong></td>
        <td width='246' bgcolor='#F0F5FF'>%s-комнатная</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Этаж / Этажность</strong></td>
        <td>%s / %s</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#F0F5FF'><div align='center'><strong>Материал:</strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height='81'><ul>
      <li><strong>Фундамент:</strong> Сваи </li>
      <li><strong>Наружные стены:</strong> Армированные пенополистирольные блоки с элементами фасада </li>
      <li><strong>Внутренние стены:</strong> Монолитные ж/б и пенополистирольные блоки толщиной 200 мм </li>
      <li><strong>Внутриквартирные перегородки:</strong> Кирпичные толщиной 120 мм </li>
      <li><strong>Перекрытия:</strong> Монолитные ж/б </li>
      <li><strong>Наружная отделка здания:</strong> Облицовочная плитка </li>
    </ul>    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor='#F0F5FF'><div align='center'><strong>Площадь квартиры: </strong></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width='445' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>
      <tr>
        <td width='198'><div align='right'><strong>Общая:</strong></div></td>
        <td width='227'><div align='left'>%s</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align='right'><strong>Жилая:</strong></div></td>
        <td><div align='left'>%s</div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align='right'><strong>Кухня:</strong></div></td>
        <td><div align='left'>%s</div></td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><table width='445' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='5'>
      <tr>
        <td width='91' bgcolor='#F0F5FF'><strong>Санузел: </strong></td>
        <td width='334' bgcolor='#F0F5FF'>%s</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Лоджия:</strong></td>
        <td>%s, с остеклением (одинарное стекло на алюминиевом профиле) </td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>        
          <h3>Дополнительная информация:</h3>
          <p>Квартира предоставляется с полной отделкой, с устройством сантехприборов, электроустройств, установленными радиаторами отопления. Теплоснабжение жилого комплекса предусматривается от автономной газовой кательной. </p>
          <p><strong>Срок сдачи 3 квартал 2013 года. </strong></p>
          <h3>Контактная информация:</h3>
          <table width='445' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr>
              <td width='110' bgcolor='#F0F5FF'>Контактное лицо :</td>
              <td width='315' bgcolor='#F0F5FF'>Офис менеджер </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>E-mail:</td>
              <td><div id='mail'><a class='hideBtn' href='javascript://' onclick='hideShow(this);return false;'>
            Отправить сообщение</a><div class='hideCont'>
          <div><div id='contact-wrapper'>

            <form method='post' action='contacts_mail.php' id='inputArea'>Поля отмеченные <span class='required1'>*</span> обязательны к заполнению !
              <div>
                <label for='name'><strong>Имя:</strong><span class='required1'>*</span></label>
                <input type='text' size='50' name='contactname' id='contactname' value='' class='required' />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for='phone'><strong>Контактный телефон:</strong><span class='required1'>*</span></label>
                <input type='text' size='50' name='phone' id='phone' value='' class='required phone' />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for='email'><strong>E-mail:</strong></label>
                <input type='text' size='50' name='email' id='email' value='' class='required email' />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for='subject1'><strong>Тема:</strong><span class='required1'>*</span></label>
                <input type='text' size='50' name='subject1' id='subject1' value='Вопрос по %s-комн. квартире № %s' class='required' />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label for='message'><strong>Сообщение:</strong><span class='required1'>*</span></label>
                <textarea rows='5' cols='50' name='message' id='message' class='required'></textarea>
              </div>
              <input type='submit' value='Отправить сообщение' name='submit' />
            </form>
          </div></div></div></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr bgcolor='#F0F5FF'>
              <td>Телефоны:</td>
              <td><ul>
                <li>+7 (4852) 78-91-52 </li>
                <li>+7 (4852) 94-47-20 </li>
                <li>+7 (4852) 73-04-95</li>
              </ul></td>
            </tr>
          </table>          
          <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
        <td width='445' valign='top'><table width='420' height='74' border='0' align='center' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>
          <tr>
            <td height='74'><p>Цена: Узнать цену на данную квариру вы можете позвонив по телефонам в разделе <a href='contacts.php'>Контакты</a> </p>
            </td>" $myrow["kol_komn"], $myrow["number"], $myrow["kol_komn"], $myrow["stage"], $myrow["stage_st"], $myrow["s_ob"], $myrow["s_gil"], $myrow["s_kuh"], $myrow["san_uz"], $myrow["balkon"], $myrow["kol_komn"], $myrow["number"]);
```

Comment: @cheh1, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Запятую пропустил здесь:

```
</td>", $myrow["kol_komn"]
```

P.s. Поставь нормальную среду и прекрати писать код в блокноте.
P.s.s. "Пишите код так, как будто сопровождать его будет склонный к насилию психопат, который знает, где вы живете". (с) Макконнелл, "Совершенный код".

Comment: Спасибо Друзья!